# What is the technology behind ququer?

Tags: android, audio

I have seen a application called ququer http://xququ.com
It can using sound beep to share message or files between mobile devices and some other devices.

I think the the infomation is encoded in some format into sound,but do not know how it could be done.

Are there some mature solution for this,especially for android?

Answer (score 1):

There's two major ways to encode information in sound.  Remember that sound is a wave at a certain frequency.  You can either encode it in the volume of the sound (the amplitude of the wave) or in the frequency of the wave.  There are called amplitude modulation and frequency modulation, or AM and FM.  Just like radio, just in different frequency ranges.

AM wouldn't be too hard.  The sender would beep a known frequency sound at either 50% volume or 100% volume, and the receiver would listen on the microphone, use a band pass filter to get that frequency, and measure the volume.  FM would be a little harder, but it could use two sound files of slightly different frequencies and do the same thing-  since we want binary data it actually isn't that hard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It really helped me to start.I wonder maybe there's already some solution for AM/FM.I'm going to do a research.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make an app like this, but instead of creating awful modem-y sounds make R2D2-like sounds. Never got around to it. Anyway, to answer your question: Gabe Sechan lists two ways that sound (or any wave) can be used to transmit information. A third is called Phase Modulation.

Together these three techniques (AM, FM and PM) are the staple of how the data from one signal can be imposed on another and transmitted, but they are examples of *analog* modulation. For this application, you want *digital* modulation. This is a bit out of my expertise, so I'll refer you to Wikipedia (though maybe someone else can give a more thorough answer here):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#Digital_modulation_methods

You might also want to ask on dsp.stackexchange.com for better starting points. There's a lot to know here, but maybe I've given you enough to google some open source librarires or at least ask the right question.

Of course, you **can** use the techniques Gabe Sechan suggested, and you might find them more intuitive. Indeed, many (most? all?) digital modulation techniques use analog modulation as a starting point. However, your datarates will probably be lower.

Comment: Thanks for your basic theory.